# How to search keywords from sentences in a key-value list and get the matched result of the sentences with relative references?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I would like to search keywords from sentence with the data is in key-value list style, and return the matched sentences with the sentences references. I have been working on the checkSentence(). I know how to write to get the result only for quote:

```
def checkSentence(quote_list, searchItems):
    result_sentence = [all([searchingWord in searchingSentence for searchingWord in searchItems]) for searchingSentence in quote_list]
    return [quote_list[i] for i in range(0, len(result_sentence)) if result_sentence[i]]

checkResult = checkSentence(quote_list, searchItems)
quoteResult_list = []
for quote in checkResult:
    quoteResult_list.append(quote)

print(len(quoteResult_list))
print(quoteResult_list)
```

And now I would like to make it to get the sentences ("content" in the data, let say) with the references (the "article"). It would be something like ["The world is made of sweet.":"The World"].

There should be two for-loops that the first layer is the sentences searching and the second for-loop should be getting the "article" of the sentences. I have no idea why it doesn't work? It looks like the error is at item_list["quote"] and item_list["article"]? Many thanks!

The code is as below:

```
import json
import os

#    data part
data = {
    "title": "Vulnerable",
    "items": [
        {
            "article": "The World",
            "content": [
                "The world is made of sweet.",
                "The sweet tastes so good.",
            ]
        },
        {
            "article": "The Disaster",
            "content": [
                "That is the sweet wrapping with poison.",
                "Is that true? Are you kidding?",
            ]
        },
        {
            "article": "The Truth",
            "content": [
                "Trust me. That is not sweet!",
                "You see? That is why!",
            ]
        }
    ]
}

#    keywords for searching
searchItems = ["sweet", "is"]

#    deal with data to list
item_list = []
quote_list = []
article_list = []

for item in data["items"]:
    article = item["article"]
    for quote in item["content"]:
        item_list.append({article, quote})
        quote_list.append(quote)
        article_list.append(article)


#    check if sentences include keywords
def checkSentence(item_list, searchItems):
    for sentence in item_list["quote"]:
        result_sentence = [all([searchingWord in searchingSentence for searchingWord in searchItems]) for searchingSentence in sentence]
        sententceResult = [item_list[i] for i in range(0, len(result_sentence)) if result_sentence[i]] 
        for article in item_list["article"]:
            return_article = [all([searchingWord in searchingSentence for searchingWord in searchItems]) for searchingSentence in article]
            quoteResult = [item_list[i] for i in range(0, len(return_article)) if return_article[i]]
    return sententceResult, quoteResult

#    make the searching result as list item
checkResult = checkSentence(item_list, searchItems)
quoteResult_list = []
for quote in checkResult:
    quoteResult_list.append(quote)
print(quoteResult_list)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When adding the articles and quotes to `item_list` use tuples, as it makes it easier when finding the matches:

`item_list.append((article, quote))`

Now to the `checkSentence` function:

Because now we're using tuples, we can save both the article and corresponding sentence simultaneously. Then you only have to search for the key words in `sentence` and, if it matches, add both `article` and `sentence` to the `matches` list. Afterwards you just return the list with he results.

Here's the final code (without the data):

```
#    keywords for searching
searchItems = ["sweet", "is"]

#    deal with data to list
item_list = []
quote_list = []
article_list = []

for item in data["items"]:
    article = item["article"]
    for quote in item["content"]:
        # use tuples to make later use easier
        item_list.append((article, quote))
        quote_list.append(quote)
        article_list.append(article)

#    check if sentences include keywords
def checkSentence(item_list, searchItems):
    matches = []
    # unpack the tuples and iterate over the list
    for article, sentence in item_list:
        # check for matching key words in sentence
        if all([searchingWord in sentence for searchingWord in searchItems]):
            # add both article and sentence to the matches, if key words are present
            matches.append((article, sentence))
    return matches

#    make the searching result as list item
checkResult = checkSentence(item_list, searchItems)
print(checkResult)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Your explanation also solves my doubt of tuple that have been struggling!!